# Ionic/Meteor InAppBrowser return to app based on close or redirect url

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, ionic-view, mollie

Hi I am using a Meteor/Ionic to create an application. 
Final step in the application is to go to External Payment page (url received by Payment provider API) and come back to app after Payment is done.

Two Questions
- I can pass through a redirect url when accessing the payment page. Can I redirect back to the application based upon a specific URL ? 
- If not can I come back to the application based upon closure of the WebView ?

Client Code

```js
    this.buyGift = () => {
        this.call('newPayment', this.gift, (err, result) => {
           this.result = result;
           var paymentWindow = window.open(track.Payment, '_self');
           paymentWindow.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { 
                //How do I get back to the application? 
            });
         });
    }
```

Server Side

```js
'newPayment' : function(gift, track){
    return mollie.payments.create({
    amount: gift.price,
    description: gift.name,
    redirectUrl: 
      
      //Can I go back to the application based upon an URL? 
      
    }}
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solutions concerning this issue ?